# Voting System Thumbs up and Down Trouleshooting

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

The goal is to have Multiple images on one page and allow the general public to vote on them.  Then I have an AJAX command to remove the voting buttons and say thank you for your vote..  I can get that to work when I manually type the HTML for each image, but when I put the values into an array and want PHP to do the codes It stops working.

I use chrome and hit F12 look under the network tab when I click on either the up or the down, it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } "

I believe it has something to do with the '' and "" combinations...

I've tried it both ways same error.  when I use ' ' to wrap the variable it doesn't change the variables...

when I use the " " to wrap variables the page parses but same Uncaught syntax error.

I've tried using eval($output) that just gives a parse error on line 2...

Hopefully this is clear enough. any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<script>
function getVote(var1,var2)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById(var2).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+var1,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<? 
$shirts = "C001,C002,C003,C004";
$i = 0;
foreach (explode(",",$shirts) as $shirt) {
$i++;
$output .= "
<div align='center'>
<img src='shop/images/web/$shirt.jpg' width='250' height='293'>
<br />
<div id='poll$i' align='center'>
<a href='#' onClick='getVote('Yes,$shirt,poll$i')'><img src='/images/vtu.jpg' width='50' height='64'></a>
<a href='#' onClick='getVote('No,$shirt,poll$i')'><img src='/images/vtd.jpg' width='50' height='64'></a>
</div>
<br />";
};
echo("$output");
?>
```

Comment: `echo("$output")`  this is totally useless, you should do :  `echo $output;`

Comment: You can't `.= $output` is `$output` is not set before as `.=` needs the current value of `$output`.

Comment: What does the error say ?

Comment: Your quotes in the onclick events are no escaped and `onclick` should be all lower case

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: No semicolon `;` at the end of foreach

Comment: If i take that code outside of the foreach loop and just put in regular html and put <?= $shirt ?> etc... it works as is..

Comment: @virus: incorrect. `$undefined .= 'blah'` works just fine. PHP will auto-define the variable upon first assigment. You might get a warning, but it's not "wrong".

Comment: Yes but it might be confusing because using `.=` implies that the variable is already set while in that case it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do have mis-matched `'` and `"` in your code. You're essentially merging 3 different languages, and each uses the quotes for different purposes. Eliminate at least the PHP angle from the quoting equation by using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc):

```
echo <<<EOL
...
<div id="poll{$i}" align="center">
             ^--^-- note the use of {}
<a href="#" onclick="getVote('Yes,{$shirt},poll{$i}')"> etc...

EOL;
```

Note that your JS calls are probably incorrect as well. You're passing in a single string containing 3 different comma-separated values, but your function definition is expecting **TWO** parameter values.

Comment: Ok so I swapped out the code the way you said here now i get the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in /home/five/public_html/thefifthpoint.com/vote.php on line 32"

Comment: I also changed the Yes,{$shirt} to Yes-{$shirt},poll{$i} to not confuse anything..

Comment: Ok after reading and reading the heredoc section it turns out that there needed to be a <<<"EOL" THANK YOU!